# How to return all entries from specific date in log.nsf

Tags: date, xpages, lookup, xpages-ssjs, ssjs

I need to return all entries (collection) from a specific date from the miscellaneus view in log.nsf using SSJS.

The views first category is "text" and the second category is a "date".

I tried to use the methods getAllEntriesByKey(vector) or createViewNavFromCategory(vector) but I got kind of stuck as the categorized columns contain different data types.

how can I do that?

Here is one thing I tried

```
var logdb = sessionAsSigner.getDatabase("domino01/....","log.nsf");
var logView = logdb.getView("MiscEvents")

var v = new java.util.Vector()
var nav = logView.createViewNavFromCategory("domino01/...\\2019-02-15")
return nav.getCount()
```

and here is another

```
var logdb = sessionAsSigner.getDatabase("domino01/...","log.nsf");
var logView = logdb.getView("MiscEvents")
var v = new java.util.Vector()

v.add("domino01/...")
v.add(session.createDateTime("Today").getDateOnly())

var nav = logView.getAllEntriesByKey(v)
return nav.getCount()
```

[image]

Comment: Include your code.

Comment: example code included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the *getDateOnly* call from your 2nd example code.

```
v.add(session.createDateTime("Today"))
```